# How to generate document using Jsdoc in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc

I have install the Jsdoc in my solution with the help of command npm install jsdoc. Now in method I have defined with the comment as:-

```
/**
 * @param {object} state person/thing you want to say hello to.
 * @param {object} action
 * @returns {object} state
 */
```

Now the question is how can I generate the document?, what will be the command to generate the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you may have a look at the [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/index.html).
It is a bit confusing at first but quite comprehensive.

Then, I would recommend to install jsdocs globally with **npm -g**

Now you can go to your project folder and just type

```
jsdoc src -r -d docs
```

This will go through all files in the subdirectory **src** and output the documentation in **docs**.